# Display firebase database content in HTML in Angular 7

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm trying to display, all the information storaged in Firebase, in a table in HTML in Angular 7. When I use the console log, it comes all.

this is the service method:

```
  getAlquilados(){
    this.historial = this.afs.collection<historialInterface>('alquileres');
    return this.autosHistorial = this.historial.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
      return changes.map(action => {
        const datos = action.payload.doc.data() as historialInterface;
        datos.id = action.payload.doc.id;
        return datos; 
      });
    } ));
  }
```

this is the ts method:

```
constructor(private dataApiService: DataApiService) { }

  public historialAuto = [];
  public autoAlquilado = '';

  ngOnInit() {
this.dataApiService.getAlquilados().subscribe(historial => {
        console.log('Alquiler', historial);
        this.historialAuto = historial;
      });
}
```

and this is how I'm trying to display it, but nothing happens:

```
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{autoAlquilado.modelo}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously nothing would show up because 'autoAlquilado' is an empty string in your controller. You've already subscribed and assigned your returned data to 'historialAuto'. So use it inside your template. This case is for a single object. If the returned data is an array of objects, then use *ngFor on your array.

```
 <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>{{historialAuto.modelo}}</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

P.S: The better way to do this would be to use async pipe inside template, and don't subscribe it in the controller. It will help avoiding memory leaks when the component is destroyed.

Comment: Still doesn't work, but I will try the other way you recommended, thank you!